# Why can't I turn on strict checking in the node REPL?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to turn on strict checking globally.

```
> use strict;
...  // waits for more input


> "use strict";
'use strict'  // but does not turn on sanity checks
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't because every line is it's own function.

You can prepend 'use strict' to every line like this:

```
> 'use strict'; with({}){} // throws
```

Or run node `--use_strict`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Node >= 0.10.7, run `node --use_strict`.